# Kendo DropDownList - onSelect / onClose

Tags: onselect, kendo-dropdown

another question of me. Title basically says it but I was wondering what the *real* difference is in usage between the functions `onSelect` and `onClose` when using a kendo DropDownList. I have of course read the [Kendo Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#events-select) but it wasn't really clear to me what the actual differences are between `onSelect` and `onClose` . 
 I'm not 100% sure if this is a question to be asked here but still I am going to ask it as I want someone to light me up on this. So, what is the difference in usage of those two functions?

Other seen links:

- [onChange and onSelect in DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935134/onchange-and-onselect-in-dropdownlist)
- [Kendo Events Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/events)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is the order in which the events are fired. As displayed in the [demo here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/events), the `select` event is fired first, then `change`, and then the `close` event fires.

### `select` event

`select` is fired any time an item is selected by the user (note: not when selected programmatically). And, as well as passing `e.sender` in the event parameter, which is the instance of DropDownList that fired the event, it also passes `e.item`, which is the `<li>` item that was selected. You can then use that to get the model for that item if you want by passing `e.item.index()` into the `.dataItem()` method from the DropDownList, i.e.:

```
$("#list").data("kendoDropDownList").dataItem(e.item.index());
```

Something to note about the behavior of this method is that it triggers even if you select again the currently selected item. If you continually select the same item, it will keep triggering the select method.

### `change` event

`change` is fired whenever an item is selected and is different from the previous value. It differs also from the `select` method in that `e.sender` is the **only** argument passed in the event parameter, so there is no built in way to see what item is selected without digging into the methods and items in the `e.sender` object.

### `close` event

`close` is fired any time the list is closed, **even if nothing was selected**. Similar to the `change` event, the only parameter passed in the event parameter is `e.sender`. The purpose of this method is for situations where you want to trigger some behavior any time the list is closed.

Comment: from my experience select happens before the item is really selected. if e.g. you want to reload grid depending on ddl selected value doing that in onselect handler will cause using previously selected value instead of current one.

Answer (score 0):

you can get angular style feedback on the selection like so:

```
    var $disDeskSel2 = $("#disDeskSel2");
function onSelectTwo(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    $("#displayNextSelection").html('<p>You age: ' + dataItem.text + '</p>');
    $disDeskSel2.html('<p><span class="label label-primary">Based on your selection </span> You age: ' + dataItem.text + '</p>')
        .hide();
}
```