# Fire ComboBox ActionListener Event Manually

Tags: java, events, combobox

I have this `ComboBox` which I want to fire a selected option upon runtime, I know to fire a button action by using `button.doClick()`, but how can I do this in a `ComboBox` action event?

This is my `ComboBox` event:

```
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if(filters.isEmpty())
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), 2));
        else
            filters.set(0, RowFilter.regexFilter(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), 2));

        // Apply filters
        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filters));

      /*  comboBox.setSelectedItem("BAR");*/
    }
});
```

Comment: Try having a look here see if this helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306125/how-to-use-actionlistener-on-a-combobox-to-give-a-variable-a-value)

Comment: *"which I want to fire a selected option upon runtime"* - why not just run the code that the option runs outside of the action listener, like in the constructor, and mark the option as selected?

Comment: Pull the code out of the listener anon class, call it from wherever you need it. This is much simpler than trying to directly simulate the UI pipeline from your program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onChange and onSelect in DropDownList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935134/onchange-and-onselect-in-dropdownlist)

Comment: already marked my selected option on combobox but it dont triggers my action unles i select something after runtime @JonnyHenly

Comment: @Tibrogargan that question applies to html and javascript, not Java.

Comment: @ArturoMartinez I'm suggesting not to go about it by triggering the action, instead run the code that the action triggers outside of the action listener prior to presenting the ComboBox.

Comment: Is not working if i do as you suggest @JonnyHenly does anybody has an examplo where you trigger a jcombobox action?