# node.js inputting values from html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm currently making an app in node.js and want to find a way to get input from html. Currently, I want a drop down menu to call a function and use the choice as input into the function. However, when I try calling a basic function (like console.log('hello world');), nothing happens. I'm using the http module to create a server and another function to return html to the user on a localhost. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var html = buildGreeter(req);
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'Content-Length': html.length,
        'Expires': new Date().toUTCString()
    });
    res.end(html);
}).listen(8080);
function buildGreeter(req) {
var test = 'Test test test   ';
var input = '<select onchange = "myFunc()"> <option> foo </option> <option> bar </option> </select>';
return '<!DOCTYPE html> <html><header></header><body>' + test + input + '</body></html>';
}
function myFunc(variable){
    console.log(variable);
}
```

Should I be using another module? I know that a lot of examples online had the data sent to the server (ie via Ajax), but since I don't have a server for this project I don't know how applicable that solution is.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: you have a server - your nodejs application. Fact that it runs on localhost doesnt make it less of a server. Its just different address. So feel free to adopt any client-server solution that you find fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [express](http://expressjs.com/) node module which can be installed by entering `npm i express`. Here's an example of setting up a server with express with a few methods implemented as well:

```
const express = require('express')
const renderHtml = require('./util').renderHtml // Render HTML function

let app = express() // Get instance of express server

app.get('/', renderHtml('index.html')) // Home page
app.get('/other', renderHtml('other.html') // Other page

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Starting server on port ${port}`)
}
```

In another file (I've dubbed it `util.js`) you could write functions that you wanted to execute when certain paths were called on your server. For example:

```
// Render any html file that I have in my './html' directory
exports.renderHtml = function (htmlFileName) {
  return function (req, res) { 
    res.sendFile(`./html/${htmlFileName}`)
  }
}
```

You could write a drop down list like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935134/onchange-and-onselect-in-dropdownlist) and then have the onChange action be a call to another page that you specify in your server (See first code block for example).

Comment: I gave that a shot, but it tells me that renderHtml is not defined on the fourth line, most likely the fifth too. Is there a module that has to be installed? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry about that. The variable util was supposed to be renderHtml. I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Also, I didn’t clarify but you must install the express node module